# How to align button to right in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried looking this up here but I can't find anything related to this specific problem.

I'm trying to make a header which has a button on the left and right of the screen with a logo in the middle, but whenever I make the window smaller or larger the button on the right doesnt stay aligned.

[Small window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3XQ9.png)

[Large window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEVhJ.png)

Here is the code:

```
<header>
        <div id="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">               
                <div class=" col-2">
                    Menu
                </div>
                <div class="col-8 text-center ">
                    Logo
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 float-right">
                    Contact
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
     </header>
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

---

Fixed it, code now looks like this:

```
    <body> 
    <header>
        <div id="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">               
                <div class="col">
                    <span class="float-left">Menu</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col text-center">
                    Logo                       
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <span class="float-right">Contact</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
     </header>          
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wrap your content so it can be aligned according to the parent container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <div id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <span class="float-left">Menu</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 text-center">
        Logo
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <span class="float-right">Contact</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @NathanRuth Cool =D

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [flex-bootstrap-class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content) and `justify-content` for this approach:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
    <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-light">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-light">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-dark text-light">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You havn't defined what size of column grid you are using. Using col-xs,col-sm, col-md,col-lg will have different effects for the particular code. Run the snippet code in full page below and see how the col-size affects when the browser is resized.

Update - Bootstrap 4 has replaced the col-xs with col- .

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container-fluid">
  Col:xs
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-2">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 text-center ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 float-right">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div id="container-fluid">
Col:sm
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-sm-2">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 float-right">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div id="container-fluid">
Col:md
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-2">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>


<div id="container-fluid">
Col:lg
  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-lg-2">
      Menu
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 text-center ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 float-right">
      Contact
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still does not work, it should stick to the right side of the page on any screensize.

Comment: You can't just make it stick to the right using container-fluid and have column grid sizes defined. They vary depending on the screen size of the device or here the browser instead. If you want to achieve that, how about you make use of simple flexbox with float instead.